# What could cause this noise coming from attic/walls?

Tags: roof, noise

https://www.youtube.com/shorts/ZxwNdBOEiDA

Anybody ever had this problem before? Rhythmic tapping somewhere in the walls above the main bedroom.

Semi-detached house built this year I have extractor fans and a log burner. No pipes or boilers in the attic that can be seen and nothing running/on when I can hear the noise. Usually on bad nights.

Comment: Birds, tree branches?  Does it seem to increase with the wind?

Comment: "Semi-detached house" Does that mean it's attached on one side? Is it something from your neighbor's house? Do you have a new home warranty that could get the builder rep out to take a listen? What does "Usually on band nights." mean? Is _NOTHING_ on when you hear the noise, like you've turned off every breaker in your panel, so you're 100% certain that there are no mechanical devices running that could be transferring sound from elsewhere in the house to above your bedroom so you hear it when it's quiet?

Comment: extractor fan fins

Comment: How loud? Could it be a deathwatch beetle? Look up the sound on YouTube. Very common in old houses, but still could enter new houses. But my money is on extractor fan fins.

Comment: Freeman- No animals or trees nearby. Semi detached yeah so I have a neighbour on the opposite side from where noise is coming from. Builder said he will get a roofer in but he's telling me it could be anything and basically try and get used to it. Sooo everything off that I can turn off ie gas, fans, water taps etc the rhythm is faster on quiet nights so my guess is wind is blowing some sort of flap/tile/insulation?

Comment: Cheery- Could extractor fans make the noise from a few metres away? The bathroom with the fan is a few metres away or could it be the ground floor fan? The sound seems to originate from the right side of the house above the master bedroom.

Comment: Cheery- Could extractor fans make the noise from a few metres away? The bathroom with the fan is a few metres away or could it be the ground floor fan? The sound seems to originate from the right side of the house above the master bedroom